# button/onclicklistener causes app to crash

Tags: android, eclipse, onclicklistener, android-button

I have looked around looking at other questions and so far nothing has worked.  My code runs fine when I comment out the onclicklistener and its bracket of onClick it works.  This is the code I comment out.

```
//   aButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
//       @Override
//       public void onClick(View v) {
//      startActivity(new Intent (LoginActivity.this, MapActivity.class));
//  }});
```

Here is my full code for the LoginActivity (main):

```
package com.JTInc.tag;

import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBar;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.os.Build;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.util.Log;

public class LoginActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

    //Button aButton;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);



        if (savedInstanceState == null) {
            getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                    .add(R.id.container, new PlaceholderFragment()).commit();
        }
        Button aButton = (Button) this.findViewById(R.id.Button03);
         aButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
             @Override
             public void onClick(View v) {
            startActivity(new Intent (LoginActivity.this, MapActivity.class));
        }}); 

    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {

        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.login, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    /**
     * A placeholder fragment containing a simple view.
     */
    public static class PlaceholderFragment extends Fragment {

        public PlaceholderFragment() {
        }

        @Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_login,
                    container, false);
            return rootView;
        }
    }

}
```

Code for MapActivity:

```
package com.JTInc.tag;

import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBar;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.os.Build;

public class MapActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_map);

        if (savedInstanceState == null) {
            getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                    .add(R.id.container, new PlaceholderFragment()).commit();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {

        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.map, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    /**
     * A placeholder fragment containing a simple view.
     */
    public static class PlaceholderFragment extends Fragment {

        public PlaceholderFragment() {
        }

        @Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_map, container,
                    false);
            return rootView;
        }
    }

}
```

I am not very good with LogCat yet but this is what I saw under the errors category:

```
05-06 12:49:12.209: E/ActivityThread(645): Service com.android.exchange.ExchangeService has leaked ServiceConnection com.android.emailcommon.service.ServiceProxy$ProxyConnection@40d05748 that was originally bound here
05-06 12:49:12.209: E/ActivityThread(645): android.app.ServiceConnectionLeaked: Service com.android.exchange.ExchangeService has leaked ServiceConnection com.android.emailcommon.service.ServiceProxy$ProxyConnection@40d05748 that was originally bound here
05-06 12:49:12.209: E/ActivityThread(645):  at android.app.LoadedApk$ServiceDispatcher.<init>(LoadedApk.java:969)
05-06 12:49:12.209: E/ActivityThread(645):  at android.app.LoadedApk.getServiceDispatcher(LoadedApk.java:863)
05-06 12:49:12.209: E/ActivityThread(645):  at android.app.ContextImpl.bindService(ContextImpl.java:1418)
05-06 12:49:12.209: E/ActivityThread(645):  at android.app.ContextImpl.bindService(ContextImpl.java:1407)
05-06 12:49:12.209: E/ActivityThread(645):  at android.content.ContextWrapper.bindService(ContextWrapper.java:473)
05-06 12:49:12.209: E/ActivityThread(645):  at com.android.emailcommon.service.ServiceProxy.setTask(ServiceProxy.java:157)
05-06 12:49:12.209: E/ActivityThread(645):  at com.android.emailcommon.service.ServiceProxy.setTask(ServiceProxy.java:145)
05-06 12:49:12.209: E/ActivityThread(645):  at com.android.emailcommon.service.AccountServiceProxy.getDeviceId(AccountServiceProxy.java:116)
05-06 12:49:12.209: E/ActivityThread(645):  at com.android.exchange.ExchangeService.getDeviceId(ExchangeService.java:1249)
05-06 12:49:12.209: E/ActivityThread(645):  at com.android.exchange.ExchangeService$7.run(ExchangeService.java:1856)
05-06 12:49:12.209: E/ActivityThread(645):  at com.android.emailcommon.utility.Utility$2.doInBackground(Utility.java:551)
05-06 12:49:12.209: E/ActivityThread(645):  at com.android.emailcommon.utility.Utility$2.doInBackground(Utility.java:549)
05-06 12:49:12.209: E/ActivityThread(645):  at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:287)
05-06 12:49:12.209: E/ActivityThread(645):  at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:234)
05-06 12:49:12.209: E/ActivityThread(645):  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1080)
05-06 12:49:12.209: E/ActivityThread(645):  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:573)
05-06 12:49:12.209: E/ActivityThread(645):  at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)
05-06 12:49:12.230: E/StrictMode(645): null
05-06 12:49:12.230: E/StrictMode(645): android.app.ServiceConnectionLeaked: Service com.android.exchange.ExchangeService has leaked ServiceConnection com.android.emailcommon.service.ServiceProxy$ProxyConnection@40d05748 that was originally bound here
05-06 12:49:12.230: E/StrictMode(645):  at android.app.LoadedApk$ServiceDispatcher.<init>(LoadedApk.java:969)
05-06 12:49:12.230: E/StrictMode(645):  at android.app.LoadedApk.getServiceDispatcher(LoadedApk.java:863)
05-06 12:49:12.230: E/StrictMode(645):  at android.app.ContextImpl.bindService(ContextImpl.java:1418)
05-06 12:49:12.230: E/StrictMode(645):  at android.app.ContextImpl.bindService(ContextImpl.java:1407)
05-06 12:49:12.230: E/StrictMode(645):  at android.content.ContextWrapper.bindService(ContextWrapper.java:473)
05-06 12:49:12.230: E/StrictMode(645):  at com.android.emailcommon.service.ServiceProxy.setTask(ServiceProxy.java:157)
05-06 12:49:12.230: E/StrictMode(645):  at com.android.emailcommon.service.ServiceProxy.setTask(ServiceProxy.java:145)
05-06 12:49:12.230: E/StrictMode(645):  at com.android.emailcommon.service.AccountServiceProxy.getDeviceId(AccountServiceProxy.java:116)
05-06 12:49:12.230: E/StrictMode(645):  at com.android.exchange.ExchangeService.getDeviceId(ExchangeService.java:1249)
05-06 12:49:12.230: E/StrictMode(645):  at com.android.exchange.ExchangeService$7.run(ExchangeService.java:1856)
05-06 12:49:12.230: E/StrictMode(645):  at com.android.emailcommon.utility.Utility$2.doInBackground(Utility.java:551)
05-06 12:49:12.230: E/StrictMode(645):  at com.android.emailcommon.utility.Utility$2.doInBackground(Utility.java:549)
05-06 12:49:12.230: E/StrictMode(645):  at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:287)
05-06 12:49:12.230: E/StrictMode(645):  at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:234)
05-06 12:49:12.230: E/StrictMode(645):  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1080)
05-06 12:49:12.230: E/StrictMode(645):  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:573)
05-06 12:49:12.230: E/StrictMode(645):  at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)
05-06 12:49:12.230: W/ActivityManager(294): Unbind failed: could not find connection for android.os.BinderProxy@40f5dc98
05-06 12:49:12.259: E/ActivityThread(645): Service com.android.exchange.ExchangeService has leaked ServiceConnection com.android.emailcommon.service.ServiceProxy$ProxyConnection@40d05270 that was originally bound here
05-06 12:49:12.259: E/ActivityThread(645): android.app.ServiceConnectionLeaked: Service com.android.exchange.ExchangeService has leaked ServiceConnection com.android.emailcommon.service.ServiceProxy$ProxyConnection@40d05270 that was originally bound here
05-06 12:49:12.259: E/ActivityThread(645):  at android.app.LoadedApk$ServiceDispatcher.<init>(LoadedApk.java:969)
05-06 12:49:12.259: E/ActivityThread(645):  at android.app.LoadedApk.getServiceDispatcher(LoadedApk.java:863)
05-06 12:49:12.259: E/ActivityThread(645):  at android.app.ContextImpl.bindService(ContextImpl.java:1418)
05-06 12:49:12.259: E/ActivityThread(645):  at android.app.ContextImpl.bindService(ContextImpl.java:1407)
05-06 12:49:12.259: E/ActivityThread(645):  at android.content.ContextWrapper.bindService(ContextWrapper.java:473)
05-06 12:49:12.259: E/ActivityThread(645):  at com.android.emailcommon.service.ServiceProxy.setTask(ServiceProxy.java:157)
05-06 12:49:12.259: E/ActivityThread(645):  at com.android.emailcommon.service.ServiceProxy.setTask(ServiceProxy.java:145)
05-06 12:49:12.259: E/ActivityThread(645):  at com.android.emailcommon.service.ServiceProxy.test(ServiceProxy.java:191)
05-06 12:49:12.259: E/ActivityThread(645):  at com.android.exchange.ExchangeService$7.run(ExchangeService.java:1850)
05-06 12:49:12.259: E/ActivityThread(645):  at com.android.emailcommon.utility.Utility$2.doInBackground(Utility.java:551)
05-06 12:49:12.259: E/ActivityThread(645):  at com.android.emailcommon.utility.Utility$2.doInBackground(Utility.java:549)
05-06 12:49:12.259: E/ActivityThread(645):  at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:287)
05-06 12:49:12.259: E/ActivityThread(645):  at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:234)
05-06 12:49:12.259: E/ActivityThread(645):  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1080)
05-06 12:49:12.259: E/ActivityThread(645):  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:573)
05-06 12:49:12.259: E/ActivityThread(645):  at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)
05-06 12:49:12.279: E/StrictMode(645): null
05-06 12:49:12.279: E/StrictMode(645): android.app.ServiceConnectionLeaked: Service com.android.exchange.ExchangeService has leaked ServiceConnection com.android.emailcommon.service.ServiceProxy$ProxyConnection@40d05270 that was originally bound here
05-06 12:49:12.279: E/StrictMode(645):  at android.app.LoadedApk$ServiceDispatcher.<init>(LoadedApk.java:969)
05-06 12:49:12.279: E/StrictMode(645):  at android.app.LoadedApk.getServiceDispatcher(LoadedApk.java:863)
05-06 12:49:12.279: E/StrictMode(645):  at android.app.ContextImpl.bindService(ContextImpl.java:1418)
05-06 12:49:12.279: E/StrictMode(645):  at android.app.ContextImpl.bindService(ContextImpl.java:1407)
05-06 12:49:12.279: E/StrictMode(645):  at android.content.ContextWrapper.bindService(ContextWrapper.java:473)
05-06 12:49:12.279: E/StrictMode(645):  at com.android.emailcommon.service.ServiceProxy.setTask(ServiceProxy.java:157)
05-06 12:49:12.279: E/StrictMode(645):  at com.android.emailcommon.service.ServiceProxy.setTask(ServiceProxy.java:145)
05-06 12:49:12.279: E/StrictMode(645):  at com.android.emailcommon.service.ServiceProxy.test(ServiceProxy.java:191)
05-06 12:49:12.279: E/StrictMode(645):  at com.android.exchange.ExchangeService$7.run(ExchangeService.java:1850)
05-06 12:49:12.279: E/StrictMode(645):  at com.android.emailcommon.utility.Utility$2.doInBackground(Utility.java:551)
05-06 12:49:12.279: E/StrictMode(645):  at com.android.emailcommon.utility.Utility$2.doInBackground(Utility.java:549)
05-06 12:49:12.279: E/StrictMode(645):  at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:287)
05-06 12:49:12.279: E/StrictMode(645):  at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:234)
05-06 12:49:12.279: E/StrictMode(645):  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1080)
05-06 12:49:12.279: E/StrictMode(645):  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:573)
05-06 12:49:12.279: E/StrictMode(645):  at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)
05-06 12:49:12.279: W/ActivityManager(294): Unbind failed: could not find connection for android.os.BinderProxy@40fd6850
05-06 12:49:21.850: E/ThrottleService(294): problem during onPollAlarm: java.lang.IllegalStateException: problem parsing stats: java.io.FileNotFoundException: /proc/net/xt_qtaguid/iface_stat_all: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)
```

If I didn't do this properly just let me know.
All help is greatly appreciated.  Thanks!

Comment: also post  MapActivity class

Comment: Can you post your log errors ?

Comment: try to paste whole logcat.

Comment: Is this what you needed? @Kat-hat

Answer (score 2):

Initialize your button first and then write your `if(savedInstanceState==null)` condition.

Try out as below:

```
 @Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);

   Button aButton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.Button03);
     aButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
         @Override
         public void onClick(View v) {
        startActivity(new Intent (LoginActivity.this, MapActivity.class));
    }}); 

    if (savedInstanceState == null) {
        getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                .add(R.id.container, new PlaceholderFragment()).commit();
    }
}
```